# Vue JS dynamic components in routes. Handling loading and error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my vue application, I am importing the components dynamically which are then being used in the routes. So when you go to a specific route, the component chunk will be fetched dynamically.

Sometimes it takes time to fetch the components and sometimes due to network error the component couldn't be fetched. So I want to understand how can I handle the error and loading state gracefully.

Comment: I would suggest you look into axios interceptors. There you have the possibility to intercept any request and handle them according to there http status. https://github.com/axios/axios. I'll give you an example in answers.

Comment: why would a network error prevent your `vue` component from being fetched? it can prevent some data from being fetched but the component is coming from the build. 
In terms of handling data that has not come or a component simply write a catch logic in the dynamic import function or in your component.

Comment: @Michael so the build lies at the server. So to fetch that components will be a server call. I need to show the loader till the time the components is being fetched and if it couldnt fetch then I want to show the error.

Comment: Look at this. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State But I am not able to use this in router file. Where I am specifying the components for each route.

Comment: Not sure what your code looks like, the dynamic imports should happen in the component? why do you imply it is happening in the routes file?

Comment: @void I did not see this comment when posting my answer, is there any reason you cannot manipulate the `RouteConfig[]`? If there are any constraints, please update your question and include them in detail so that we can help you solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Vue allows you to define your component as a factory function that asynchronously resolves your component definition. This is called an async component factory.

Usually when we lazy load our router views with Webpack we do:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@views/home'),
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //               The `import` function returns a Promise with our component definition.
  },
] // RouteConfig[]
```

But, what happens when we need to [handle the loading state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State)?

Since Vue `2.3.0` and Vue Router `2.4.0`, the async component factory can also return an object:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => ({
      // The component to load (should be a Promise)
      component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
      // A component to use while the async component is loading
      loading: LoadingComponent,
      // A component to use if the load fails
      error: ErrorComponent,
      // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
      delay: 200,
      // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
      // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
      timeout: 3000
    })
  },
] // RouteConfig[]
```

---

You may want to reuse the same loading and error components for different views, along with some delay and timeout defaults. If that is the case, you can use a strategy found in this [vue enterprise boilerplate](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate) created by [Chris Fritz](https://github.com/chrisvfritz), a Vue core team member.

```
// Lazy-loads view components, but with better UX. A loading view
// will be used if the component takes a while to load, falling
// back to a timeout view in case the page fails to load. You can
// use this component to lazy-load a route with:
//
// component: () => lazyLoadView(import('@views/my-view'))
//
// NOTE: Components loaded with this strategy DO NOT have access
// to in-component guards, such as beforeRouteEnter,
// beforeRouteUpdate, and beforeRouteLeave. You must either use
// route-level guards instead or lazy-load the component directly:
//
// component: () => import('@views/my-view')
//
function lazyLoadView(AsyncView) {
  const AsyncHandler = () => ({
    component: AsyncView,
    // A component to use while the component is loading.
    loading: require('@views/_loading').default,
    // Delay before showing the loading component.
    // Default: 200 (milliseconds).
    delay: 400,
    // A fallback component in case the timeout is exceeded
    // when loading the component.
    error: require('@views/_timeout').default,
    // Time before giving up trying to load the component.
    // Default: Infinity (milliseconds).
    timeout: 10000,
  })

  return Promise.resolve({
    functional: true,
    render(h, { data, children }) {
      // Transparently pass any props or children
      // to the view component.
      return h(AsyncHandler, data, children)
    },
  })
}
```

And use it like so:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => lazyLoadView(import('@views/home')),
  },
] // RouteConfig[]
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for providing this answer. Just a question, does this "handling loading state" only works on vue-router like your example and not in AFile.Vue components: {}?

Comment: @user3779015 It should work in a SFC components option too. Just make sure you are using Vue v2.3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using axios to handle your requests there is the possibility to intercept any request and handle them for example according to there status.

Here's an example which redirects to Login if response return error code is 401 (unauthorized).
One thing to mention is that you can have interceptors for responses and requests.

Documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        router.push('/logout');
    }

    return error;
});
```